# No activity found to handle custom intent

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-intent

Using a customer defined activity and i've declared the intent action in the manifest.xml
Here's the manifest file with the error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="course.labs.dangerousapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!--
          TODO - Using a permission element,
          define a custom permission with name
              "course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM" 
          and "dangerous" protection level.
    -->
    <permission
        android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
        >
     </permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- TODO - enforce the custom permission on this Activity -->

        <activity
            android:permission="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"
            android:name=".DangerousActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <!--
                 TODO - add additional intent filter info so that this Activity
                  will respond to an Implicit Intent with the action
                  "course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY"
            -->
            <intent-filter >
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's where the intent was invoked in the program

### Code:

```
package course.labs.permissionslab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GoToDangerousActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Lab-Permissions";
    private static final String DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_ACTION = "course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.go_to_dangerous_activity);
        Button startDangerousActivityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_dangerous_activity_button);
        startDangerousActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startDangerousActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startDangerousActivity() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered startDangerousActivity()");
        startActivity(new Intent(DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any other info will hell, I've been tried everything i know and not sure why i'm getting this error again.

Answer (score 0):

Try so:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_ACTION.class));
```

This is the normail way of doing it

**[EDIT]**

OR (note the different declaration of DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_ACTION)

```
private static final String DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_ACTION = ".DangerousActivity";
// ...
startActivity(new Intent(DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_ACTION));
```

I use this in a SplashScreen Activity to call the Main Activity (after done loading my graphics from SVG files).

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I tried that and the only option was .getclass() and doing that gives me the same error. Besides DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_ACTION is declared at the top as a string and not a class

Comment: I believe intent takes in a context and class as variables? DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_ACTION is a string and using that as a class gives me an error still

Comment: Strange - I use the second method in a SplashScreen Activity to call my main Activity. I use the first method in all other (normal) cases (which is why I proposed it as first).

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the first App that has the manifest before calling using the second App?

**[EDIT]**

To check if a activity is registered to some Intent, you can use adb.exe available on Platform-tools folder to list all intents configured on the device.

To do that, on prompt execute the command below:

```
adb shell dumpsys package > packages.txt
```

Then open packages.txt and find for action name course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY. Should have a activity associate with that action.

Comment: Yes, i installed the first one and it runs fine. The error in the second one has been pointing to "No Activity found to handle intent course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY

Comment: This error message appears when it has not activity registered with that action name. That's why I thought that it was not installed.

Comment: I did that and couldn't find any activity with that name, how can i fix that please?

Comment: Seems that the first app isn't installed on same device that the second app. The manifest shown by you belongs to the first app, right?

Comment: Just to clarify, the constant course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY is the action name, not the activity name. Several activities can meet requests of this action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run "DangerousApp" before running "GoToDangerousActivity".

Answer (score 0):

This is because your dangerous app is not even installed on the device. If you were trying to do this from android studio, by default studio would try to launch the app which won't be successful because of the permission it needs. To install your dangerours, modify studio's launch settings to not to run the app right away. I got the same issue.